# Point cloud registration using PCL Iterative closest point

Tags: c++11, transform, point-cloud-library

I try to perform ICP with PCL,

but   `pcl::transformPointCloud` doesn't work. This my code:

```
int
 main ()
{
   pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr cloudIn (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);
   pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr cloudOut (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);
   pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> finalCloud ;
   pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> finalCloud1 ;
   pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr cloudOut_new (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>) ;

   if(pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("/ICP_PCL/000.pcd", *cloudIn)==-1)
   {
     PCL_ERROR ("Couldn't read first file! \n");
     return (-1);
   }

   if(pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("/ICP_PCL/001.pcd", *cloudOut)==-1)
   {
     PCL_ERROR ("Couldn't read second input file! \n");
     return (-1);
   }

  pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<pcl::PointXYZI, pcl::PointXYZI> icp;
  icp.setInputCloud(cloudOut);
  icp.setInputTarget(cloudIn);
  icp.setMaximumIterations (500);
  icp.setTransformationEpsilon (1e-9);
  icp.setMaxCorrespondenceDistance (0.05);
  icp.setEuclideanFitnessEpsilon (1);
  icp.setRANSACOutlierRejectionThreshold (1.5);

  icp.align(finalCloud);

  if (icp.hasConverged())
  {
      std::cout << "ICP converged." << std::endl
                << "The score is " << icp.getFitnessScore() << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Transformation matrix:" << std::endl;
      std::cout << icp.getFinalTransformation() << std::endl;
  }
  else std::cout << "ICP did not converge." << std::endl;

  Eigen::Matrix4f transformationMatrix = icp.getFinalTransformation ();
  std::cout<<"trans %n"<<transformationMatrix<<std::endl;

  pcl::transformPointCloud( *cloudOut, *cloudOut_new, transformationMatrix);

  pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII ("/ICP_PCL/IcpResult3.pcd", finalCloud);

  finalCloud1=*cloudIn;
  finalCloud1+=*cloudOut_new;

   boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer (new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer("3D Viewer"));
   viewer->setBackgroundColor(0,0,0);
   pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<pcl::PointXYZI> single_color1 (cloudIn, 0, 0, 200);
   pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<pcl::PointXYZI> single_color2 (cloudOut_new, 200, 0, 0);

   viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> (cloudIn,single_color1, "sample_cloud_1");
   viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> (cloudOut_new, single_color2, "sample_cloud_2");

    viewer->addCoordinateSystem(1.0);
      while(!viewer->wasStopped())
      {
          viewer->spinOnce();
          boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::microseconds(100000));
      }
 return (0);
}
```

and this is what I get as result: 
[image]

The `transformpointcloud` is not working, but the saved PCD file having two clouds looks fine. Can someone please suggest me what is happening?

Answer (score 14):

The problem lies in bad initialisation of the algorithmic parameters. You choose the following parameters for your ICP Algorithm:

```
icp.setInputCloud(cloudOut);
icp.setInputTarget(cloudIn);
icp.setMaximumIterations (500);
icp.setTransformationEpsilon (1e-9);
icp.setMaxCorrespondenceDistance (0.05);
icp.setEuclideanFitnessEpsilon (1);
icp.setRANSACOutlierRejectionThreshold (1.5);
```

The value for `setMaximumIterations()` should be larger if the initial alignment is poor and small if the initial alignment is already quite good. A value of `500` iterations is to high and should be decreased to a value in the range of `10 - 100` (You can always increase this later when fine-tuning).

The value for `setRANSACOutlierRejectionThreshold()` should typically be just below the resolution of your scanner, e.g,

The value for `setMaxCorrespondenceDistance()` should be set to approx. 100 times the value of `setRANSACOutlierRejectionThreshold()` (This depends on how good your initial guess is and can also be fine-tuned).

The value for `setTransformationEpsilon()` is your convergence criterion. If the sum of differences between current and last transformation is smaller than this threshold, the registration succeeded and will terminated. A value of `(1e-9)` seems quite reasonable and should give good initial results.

The value `setEuclideanFitnessEpsilon()` is an divergence threshold. Here you can define the delta between two consecutive steps in the ICP loop for which the algorithm stops. That means that you can set an euclidean distance error barrier if the ICP diverges at some point, so that it does not become even worse over the remaining number of iterations.

More information about how to set the parameters can be found here:

- [PCL ICP presentation](http://www.pointclouds.org/assets/files/presentations/ICCV2011-registration.pdf)
- [Paper about registration with PCL](http://lgg.epfl.ch/~ichim/registration_tutorial_ram_2015/data/registration_paper_tutorial_ram_2015.pdf)
- [PCL Mailing list about ICP 1](http://www.pcl-users.org/How-to-determine-the-registration-parameters-in-icp-td4024038.html)
- [PCL Mailing list about ICP 2](http://www.pcl-users.org/Suggestions-for-poor-ICP-Alignment-td4022706.html)
- [PCL ICP documentation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_iterative_closest_point.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with pointers and you don't need some lines. Use this code:

```
int main ()
{
   pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr cloudIn (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);
   pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr cloudOut (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);
   pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr finalCloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);
   pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr cloudOut_new (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>) ;

   if(pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("/ICP_PCL/000.pcd", *cloudIn)==-1)
   {
     PCL_ERROR ("Couldn't read first file! \n");
     return (-1);
   }

   if(pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("/ICP_PCL/001.pcd", *cloudOut)==-1)
   {
     PCL_ERROR ("Couldn't read second input file! \n");
     return (-1);
   }

  pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<pcl::PointXYZI, pcl::PointXYZI> icp;
  icp.setInputCloud(cloudOut);
  icp.setInputTarget(cloudIn);
  icp.setMaximumIterations (500);
  icp.setTransformationEpsilon (1e-9);
  icp.setMaxCorrespondenceDistance (0.05);
  icp.setEuclideanFitnessEpsilon (1);
  icp.setRANSACOutlierRejectionThreshold (1.5);

  icp.align(*cloudOut_new);

  if (icp.hasConverged())
  {
      std::cout << "ICP converged." << std::endl
                << "The score is " << icp.getFitnessScore() << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Transformation matrix:" << std::endl;
      std::cout << icp.getFinalTransformation() << std::endl;
  }
  else std::cout << "ICP did not converge." << std::endl;

  *finalCloud=*cloudIn;
  *finalCloud+=*cloudOut_new;

  pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII ("/ICP_PCL/IcpResult3.pcd", *finalCloud);

   boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer (new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer("3D Viewer"));
   viewer->setBackgroundColor(0,0,0);
   pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<pcl::PointXYZI> single_color1 (cloudIn, 0, 0, 200);
   pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<pcl::PointXYZI> single_color2 (cloudOut_new, 200, 0, 0);

   viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> (cloudIn,single_color1, "sample_cloud_1");
   viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> (cloudOut_new, single_color2, "sample_cloud_2");

    viewer->addCoordinateSystem(1.0);
      while(!viewer->wasStopped())
      {
          viewer->spinOnce();
          boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::microseconds(100000));
      }
 return (0);
}
```

Comment: it still does not work, here my 2 pcd files :                                  https://app.box.com/s/tdaxtzcjsas8f3p39nxbzmprqw7x5bxt

https://app.box.com/s/jgvz2ns02fc6g2w46jryzresanb4l8qf

Comment: According to your clouds, you have to estimate an initial alignment to help ICP converging. Try [SAC-IA](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_sample_consensus_initial_alignment.html) before running ICP, and then tune the ICP parameters accordingly. That should lead you to a good registration.

Comment: could you explain the differences between `finalCloud` and `cloudOut_new` ?

Comment: @FäridAlijani `finalCloud` is the final point cloud with both input clouds `cloudIn` and `cloudOut` merged and alligned. `cloudOut_new` is `cloudOut` after its registration onto `cloudIn`.

Comment: so what you are proposing is to consider frame_0 as a target and frame_1 as source? I kinda do not agree! imagine I have 1000 point cloud frames that I would like to use pairwise registration to create a 3d model. what I am doing in my code is to consider frame(i) as a source, and frame(i+1) as a target to calculate the transformation matrix with ICP.

Comment: @FäridAlijani I'm just assuming the same name convention the questioner used. And actually it does make sense to call "input cloud" the one that is going to be fixed and "ouptut cloud" the one that is going to be transformed. These clouds could be unordered, so you are talking about a different scenario. This is a specific case of two point clouds registration, not 1000 video frames. In your scenario we can assume interframe similarity, so a standard ICP would work. Here, before applying ICP, we need to perform a good initial alignment due to little similarity between both point clouds.

Comment: I get a core dump :(. test_lidar_scanpair_alignment: /build/pcl-OilVEB/pcl-1.8.1+dfsg1/kdtree/include/pcl/kdtree/impl/kdtree_flann.hpp:136: int pcl::KdTreeFLANN<PointT, Dist>::nearestKSearch(const PointT&, int, std::vector<int>&, std::vector<float>&) const [with PointT = pcl::PointXYZ; Dist = flann::L2_Simple<float>]: Assertion `point_representation_->isValid (point) && "Invalid (NaN, Inf) point coordinates given to nearestKSearch!"' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: @mkuse it seems you are getting data from LIDAR with some NaN values. Clean up your cloud first and get rid of that invalid data before running your KdTreeFLANN algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `setMaxCorrespondenceDistance` to 0.005 (because my point cloud is around this value) and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the input cloud, maybe you should try `setInputSource()` defined in `icp.h`, instead of `setInputCloud()`, which is a base function. I know this sounds nuts, but it does make a difference in my case (PCL 1.8.1)